# Cassandra - Data Replication across regions

Tags: cassandra, cluster-computing, replication

I have a Cassandra Cluster running in EC2, which is composed of 3 nodes, so far my configuration is pretty straight forward, 2 of them are seeds, I'm using EC2Snitch and I can insert data with a replica factor of 2 and it works fine so far.

Now I need to create a new instance of my application running in another EC2 region which will have another Cassandra Cluster running.

What are configuration aspects to look at if I need both rings the replicate data between them, eventually I need both rings to have the same information? Things like EC2MultiRegionSnitch, etc

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When setting up multi-dc replication the key things you need to look into are

Operationally

```
1) Changing the Broadcast addresses to the public IP's so the nodes can communicate
2) Changing the seed to the public IP address
3) Changing the snitch to EC2MultiRegion Snitch
```

Then follow the standard instructions
[Adding a DC](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/operations/ops_add_dc_to_cluster_t.html)

[EC2MultiRegionSnitch](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/architecture/architectureSnitchEC2MultiRegion_c.html)